# Setting edit text of fragment from Activity giving null pointer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have just started using fragments. I have created a edit text in fragment and I want to fill it from activity but it is giving me null pointer exception. May be OnCreateView runs after fragmenttransaction is committed. I have made it working from another way but I am just a little curious why it is not working. I have searched it but could not find answer of my problem. Any help would be appreciated

Here is my code In activity:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Myfragment mFragment = new Myfragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

mFragment.set_fragment_editext("Hello world");//setting edit text in fragment throws exception
```

Then in fragment class:

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment {
    EditText edittext_fragment;

    public static Myfragment newInstance() {
        return new Myfragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Myfragment, container, false);
        InitializeFragment(myInflatedView);
        return myInflatedView;
    }

    private void InitializeFragment(View myInflatedView) {
        edittext_fragment = (EditText) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_fragment_caption);
    }

    public void set_fragment_editext(String value) {
        edittext_fragment.setText(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oncreateview is called after you call the setText function, hence the null pointer.

Pass the string as an argument.

```
public class Myfragment extends Fragment { 
EditText edittext_fragment; 
String textViewText;

public static Myfragment newInstance(String textViewText){ 
this.textViewText = textViewText;
return new Myfragment(); 
} 

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Myfragment, container, false);
InitializeFragment(myInflatedView); 
set_fragment_editext(textViewText);
return myInflatedView; 
} 

private void InitializeFragment(View myInflatedView) { 
edittext_fragment = (EditText) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_fragment_caption); 
} 
private void set_fragment_editext(String value) { 
edittext_fragment.setText(value); 
} 
}
```

Activity code:

```
Myfragment mFragment = Myfragment.newInstance("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) It takes some time to pass through fragment lifecycle.

2) It happens in the background.

```
Myfragment mFragment = new Myfragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

// EditText is not yet initialized
mFragment.set_fragment_editext("Hello world");//setting edit text in fragment throws exception
```

It is common android task that you should do some things only when some components are inittialized.

In your case you can do this in several ways:

1) Postpone string set.

```
class Myfragment extedns Fragment {
    private String mEditTextString;
    private EditText edittext_fragment;

    public void setEditText(String string) {
        mEditTextString = string;
        if (edittext_fragment != null) {
            edittext_fragment.setText(string);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeFragment(View myInflatedView) {
        edittext_fragment = (EditText) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_fragment_caption);
        if (mEditTextString != null) {
            edittext_fragment.setText(mEditTextString);
        }
    }
}
```

2) By callback to activity when edit text is inititlized. Please take a look at this guide https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

3) As mentioned by @Karishnu Poddar if you want to set edit text just once you can pass it to fragment arguments

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer seems to be correct one

Comment: @SimpleMan Thruly speaking there is a problem with this solution. onAttachFragment is called before onViewCreated in the Fragment. Please wait a minute and I will fix my solution :)

Comment: @SimpleMan I fixed my answer. Sorry for first one with onAttachFragment()